# iOS Core Bluetooth no disconnect notification

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, disconnect, cbperipheral

I'm developing an app using CoreBluetooth and I need to be notified if the bluetooth connection is lost. I establish connection with many BLE devices, put the app into background mode and wait for disconnect notification. The problem is I get didDisconnect method is invoked only if I push the off button on my BLE device but not when I get out of range. Do you have any idea why this could happen?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Devices don't disconnect automatically when they get away from each other. You have to do that by yourself.

Comment: How app should know that Device is not in range now, or powered off ? 
(Consider that app is in foreground only)